# Can I get JSONObject from Default value of Firebase Remote Config

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I need to fetch `JSONObject` from default value of Remote `config` in `Firebase`. By `FirebaseRemoteConfig.getString()`, it gets converted to the String, but not in the `JSONObject`, saying

> `org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character xx`

I am attaching default values of remote `config` below:

```
  <entry>
    <key>welcome_message</key>
    <value>{"version" :1,"type":"category","name":"CATEGORY"}
    </value>
  </entry>
```

I am now attaching my Java Code below:

```
  String welcomeMessage = mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getString(WELCOME_MESSAGE_KEY);

  JSONObject categoryListInJson = new JSONObject(welcomeMessage);
```

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: Print String wc , is it a well-formated json ?

Comment: No, it's not @semako

Comment: Can you paste the content of welcomeMessage ? and also in "org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character xx", what is the value of xx ? @vipul-k-patil

Comment: I've already done this in the question. String comes as: {version:1,type:category,name:BASE CATEGORY} and the value of "xx" is 36, i.e. the Space Character- " "

Comment: looks like xml tag value has json.

Comment: Yes, I need to pass it as json. @Raghunandan

Comment: Valid Json need quotes around field name and strings, like this {"version":1,"type":"category","name":"BASE CATEGORY"}. You may have it well formatted in your remote config, but you also have to make sure that the string in your runtime has a correct format. Also, the space may come from here BASE[Here]CATEGORY. So missing "", I guess.

Comment: That's the issue. I am not getting the proper format at runtime from the above stated format. Also, the issue of <SPACE> will be gone if double quotes are available after getString()

Comment: I solved it using older gradle version. Check this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/48072301/5137352

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53962895/3130610

Comment: any updates for this thread?

Answer (score 1):

It's bug on Android Studio 3.0 or above.

Comment: You're right. I solved it by using `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'` https://stackoverflow.com/a/48072301/5137352

Answer (score 0):

I saw a bug where the quotes from strings were getting stripped when picking values from default.xml

Can you try either of 2 things?

1. Enable developer mode and set cache expiration to 0. Then setup the JSON on firebase remote config console. Then make a fetch on device. This is because the bug isn't when JSON is fetched from console, it seemed only when pulling value from default xml.
2. Instead of using a string in default.xml JSON, use a number - and see if that works?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### There are multiple solutions for this problem

**1.** Use *firebaseConfig.setDefaults(Map);* for setting up the default configuration.

**2.** Use backslash () before Double Quotes(") in your String in .xml file.

**3.** Replace

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1' with
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
and 
google() with
maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
```

**4.** Add *android.enableAapt2 = false* in gradle.properties